# How To Get Data from Db in intellij in Soring Framework using spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sql-server-2008-r2, spring-framework-beans

[image: postman3][Postman Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBmsO.jpg) [Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBBjW.jpg)I want to get employee data but this error showing.
what is the solution for this?
I have included all dependencies

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-12-21T12:53:24.307+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/bookme/getEmpById"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Without any code, it is hard to tell what is causing this problem.

Comment: Can you add your controller code here?

Comment: yes Sure. i upload it again

Comment: SSK

        public class EmployeeGetApi {


            @Autowired
            private EmployeeService employeeService;

            @GetMapping("/getEmpById")

            public String getEmpById() {
                TblEmp tblEmp= employeeService.getEmpById(1);
                return tblEmp.getName();

Comment: @SSK check image link for clear code image

Comment: @RoarS Please Check img link for clear code image

Comment: If you compare the path in the error message with the path in your GetMapping, you'll see a difference.

Comment: @RoarS What is the difference??

Comment: @RoarS  I added "server.servlet.context-path=/bookme" in application properties thats why on localhost i put /bookme/getEmpID

Comment: Well, error message states it is a routing issue. Without any knowledge on how you are testing this, it is really hard/impossible to tell. Maybe you are running POST or PUT requests against this end-point, or maybe `server.servlet.context-path` is misconfigured, there are many possible sources for this error.

Comment: @RoarS I am trying to get employee data using emp id

Comment: Let's make a final attempt to solve this: Can you make a screen-shot of how you are testing this? I would like to see the full URL with parameters  if any in this screen-shot.

Comment: I am testing on POSTMAN also on browser and uploaded a screenshot. if you can see then please

Comment: can you do personnel chat with me so its easy to discuss and share things??

Comment: @RoarS Please Click on Browser Screenshot and Postman ScreenShot Link top of my question  to view my testing images

Comment: Thanks, and there was the error. You are using `/bookme/get/EmpById` in Postman. The correct URL is ``/bookme/getEmpById`

Comment: @RoarS Sorry, I did not get. its a same url you give to me.. can you please make it clear ?

Comment: Please have a look at the screen-shot to the left you just added. I don't think we are making any progress now, so I think it is best if a new person can help you further. BR

Comment: @RoarS yeah i got your point but again its a same error. i putted another one screenshot of postman3.. look at that

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the **server.servlet.context-path** property? If configured, add it to the port

Comment: server.servlet.context-path is configured and port is also... but tell me which type of configurattion you wanna say>?